# How to use python to turn a .dbf into a shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I have been scouring the internet trying to find a pythonic (sp?!) way to process this data..

Everyday we will recieve a load of data in .dbf format (hopefully) - we then need to save this data as a shapefile.

Does anyone have any links or any suggestions as to my process?

Comment: Im running armap 9.3.1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was in model builder all along!

```
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: DBF2SHAPEFILE <XY_Table> <Y_Field> <X_Field> <Output_Feature_Class>
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, datetime

# Adds the creation date to all of the previous shapefiles in that folder
filename = 'D:/test.txt'
fileinfo = os.stat(filename)
creation_date = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(fileinfo.st_ctime)
os.rename(filename, filename + '-' + creation_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...
XY_Table = sys.argv[1]

Y_Field = sys.argv[2]

X_Field = sys.argv[3]

Output_Feature_Class = sys.argv[4]

# Local variables...
Layer_Name_or_Table_View = ""

# Process: Make XY Event Layer...
gp.MakeXYEventLayer_management(XY_Table, X_Field, Y_Field, Layer_Name_or_Table_View, "")

# Process: Copy Features...
gp.CopyFeatures_management(Layer_Name_or_Table_View, Output_Feature_Class, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alice, Don't forget to assign a spatial reference to your xy layer!  Or you can do it to the output feature class using

```
gp.DefineProjection_managment(Output_Feature_Class, coor_system)
```

Comment: The "MakeXYEventLayer_management" contains a parameter for projection.

Answer (score 2):

This is not python as requested, but this will run a macro in visual basic.
Macros > Visual Basic Editor.
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/25252

Possible arcpy script (though publisher is not supported in arcpy):

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/1200-beta-10-arcpy-and-pmf

Comment: Arcpy isn't there at v9.3.1.

Comment: It turns out i was described the problem incorrectly - its not the .pmf we need to update it is the shapefile! Which we then need to export to the client - do you have any links for this?

Comment: ive edited my question with all of my new found problems!

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in Python. See the following help document for code examples of how to do this:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/dotnet/9ce6663f-1e34-4e84-923a-0d8f671ec730.htm

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1. Read your dbf file into memory with [this dbf reader and writer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362715-dbf-reader-and-writer/)
2. Iterate through the dbf records and bring them into a shapefile with something similar to Listing 9 in [this ArcUser article](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0708/files/tappingpython.pdf).